# largest and others constraints in portfolio optimization (MILP problem) CVXPY

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy

Here is `python` code in `cvxpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
import cvxpy as cp
n = 10

a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)

b = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
c = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
d = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)

x = cp.Variable(shape=n, boolean=True)

# objective function 
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(x,a)))

# constraints
constraints = []
constraints.append(cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, b) <= 50) # constraint 1
constraints.append(cp.sum_largest(cp.hstack([
    cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, b)), 
    cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, c)), 
    cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, d))]), 2) <= 100) # constraint 2

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
# solve model
prob.solve(solver=cp.CBC, verbose=False, maximumSeconds=100)
print("status:", prob.status)
```

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`  and `x` are all binary. The objective is `max(sum(x*a))` and the constraints are:

1. `sum(x*b) <= 50`
2. `sum of the largest 2 values in [sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)] <= 100`, this is implemented via [sum_largest](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.other_atoms.html#sum-largest) `sum_largest([x*a, x*b, x*c], 2) <= 100`
3. define `others=[b, c, d] - b - (largest 2 value in [b, c, d])`

   For example:

   case1: `[sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)] = [1,2,3]`, so `(largest 2 value in [b, c, d]) = [c, d]` and **others=[b, c, d] - b - [c, d] = None**

   case2: `[sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)] = [3,2,1]`, so `(largest 2 value in [b, c, d]) = [b, c]` and **others=[b, c, d] - b - [b, c] = d**

   constriants:

   ```py
   for i in others:
    constraints.append(cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, i) <= 10)
   ```

Constraints 1, 2 have already been implemented. How can I implement **constraint 3**? Is it even possible in `cvxpy`?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: the question has changed, so this is no longer a valid answer.**

The original problem was:

```
(1) sum(x*b) <= 5 
(2) max([sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)]) <= 10 
(3) define others=[b, c, d] - b - maxBCD([b, c, d]) (others is a set of symbols, maxBCD returns a symbol)
    for i in others:  
         constraints.append(cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, i) <= 1)
```

This is an answer to that original problem statement. I have not deleted the answer as it is a good starting point (also because the answer states the problem a bit more precisely: in mathematical terms).

(1) and (2) can be written as:

```
  xb = sum(x*b)
  xc = sum(x*c)
  xd = sum(x*d)

  xb <= 5
  xc <= 10
  xd <= 10
```

(3) needs to know which one is the maximum. I assume two or all three can be maximum.

```
   bIsMax,cIsMax,dIsMax: binary variables
    
   # bisMax=1 => xb is largest
   xb >= xc - (1-bisMax)*10
   xb >= xd - (1-bisMax)*10
   # cisMax=1 => xc is largest
   xc >= xb - (1-cisMax)*5
   xc >= xd - (1-cisMax)*10
   # disMax=1 => xd is largest
   xd >= xb - (1-disMax)*5
   xd >= xc - (1-disMax)*10
   # at least one of them is largest
   bIsMax + cIsMax + dIsMax >= 1
```

Note that `others=[b, c, d] - b- maxBCD` can be restated as: `others=[c, d] - maxBCD`.

```
   # if c is not max then xc<=1
   xc <= 1 + 9*cIsMax
   # if d is not max then xd<=1
   xd <= 1 + 9*dIsMax
```

Left to the reader:

1. check the math and implement in CVXPY.
2. update the answer to the revised question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works well for the constraints above and is easy to implement in `cvxpy`. But my problem would be a little bit more complicated: actually the constriant (2) should be: `sum_largest([sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)], 2) <= 10`. For example: `[sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)] = [1,2,3]`, `sum_largest([sum(x*b), sum(x*c), sum(x*d)], 2)  = 3+2 = 5`. In that case, how can I reprensent `xb is the top 2 largest`?

Comment: That is a bit different. Obviously, I can only work with what is in the question. My mind-reading skills are too limited to guess the problem is actually something different.

Comment: question edited to provide more details. please check constraint 3 ;)

Comment: Great. I am sure someone will produce an answer for the new problem.